# Sum of random variables - is there an efficient way to do inference?

Tags: statistical-inference, bayes-theorem

Suppose I have a series of variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$.  I have $S = \sum_i^n X_i$.  Now suppose that I have a constraint on the distribution of S, for example from some data.

Looking at any of the $X$ values, Bayes theorem gives that:

$P(X_j \mid S, X_{-j}) \propto P(S \mid \{X_i\} )\, P(X_j)$.  This means that if you know all of the other $X$ values other than $X_i$ and $S$ you can sample $X_j$.  This is basically just Gibbs sampling if you iterate over the values.  The problem is that this is not very efficient - the sum constraints mean that different $X_i$ values will be anticorrelated with each other

You can try drawing from the joint distribution:
$P(\{X_i\} \mid S) \propto P(S \mid \{X_i\}) \, P(\{X_i\})$, but this is requires for example the Metropolis Hastings algorithm with all the commensurate tuning.

I am wondering if there is some efficient way to do this sampling, perhaps by drawing a value of $S$, and then conditional on that sampling the other variables conditional on this.  This requires implementing a sum constraint on the problem, however, and I don't know how to do this.

Any suggestions?

I'm happy to make the assumption that $\{X_i\}$ and $P(S)$ are all normally distributed, and even independent if necessary.